# React Player Thumbnail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, react-player

i am using react-player for playing videos. Not sure if there are any better options, but this seems to do the job. The only issue i have is, that i need to get thumbnails for the videos. Any idea how i would go around it ?

If you know about some better option for playing videos in React web app with supported thumbnails, that would be also great.

```
<ReactPlayer                                                    
 className="videoFrame"
 url={url}
 playing
 controls
/>
```

Thanks

Edit: I ended up using the video itself as thumbnail and blocking all mouse events over it. Then use parent div as button. In case of youtube i replace the video with thumbnail provided by youtube ( https://img.youtube.com ), because of the big play button over video. Most of other players dont have it.

Comment: As a workaround you could display and img tag that you can hide when the video starts playing. Only issue would be to create the image tho

Comment: Yeah, thats the hard part :) i realy dont know how to go around creating the thumbnail images for all the possible video services ( youtube, vimeo, dailymotion etc. )

Comment: just checked and found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-video-thumbnail might help you. Given URL returns you a thumbnail

Answer (score 12):

Use the `light` prop to supply an image URL to the player.

```
<ReactPlayer                                                    
 className="videoFrame"
 url={url}
 light="http://placekitten.com/200/300"
 playing
 controls
/>
```

Comment: How to make ```light``` always fit hight

Comment: This solution isn't very good. It does not allow video to play on click.

Comment: @GaneshMB check this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player#responsive-player

Answer (score 3):

If you have an specific image that you want to be the thumbnail, you should set the image URL to light:

```
 <ReactPlayer                                              
       url='https://vimeo.com/243556536'
       light = 'https://sampleimage.com'
       playing
       controls/>
```

If you want to display the thumbnail of the video, you'll just have to set light to true:

```
<ReactPlayer                                              
      url='https://vimeo.com/243556536'
      light = {true}
      playing
      controls/>
```

Check the documentation of react-player on this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture first frame of video as image than save it and use. But this used when you are working with image processing. I am recommending following options
Please check here-
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player
otherwise use go through this link-
https://video-react.js.org/

Comment: Thanks, i am using the react-player, i tried the second one as well, but it was not working that well ( didnt support as many sources ). Could you suggest any way how to capture the first frame of the video ? I would need to do that when user submits the video link.

Comment: which URL are you using?

Comment: Please check this link. It may help you also https://jsfiddle.net/e6w3rtj1/

Comment: Why do you need to capture the first frame of the video when you can set the light to true in react-player?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a pester image, then they have something built-in.

```
    <Player
      poster="/assets/poster.png"
      src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"
    />
```

[here is where i found it](https://video-react.js.org/components/poster-image/#:%7E:text=%3CPlayer%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20poster%3D%22/assets/poster.png%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20src%3D%22https%3A//media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4%22%0A%20%20%20%20/%3E%0A%20%20) . I was looking for somthing els, came aross this and then your post, so I thought I'd share it.